# Удаление файлов в репозитории с их сохранением в другом месте при git pull

Tags: git

Как можно удалить файлы из локального (localhost) и удаленного (Bitbucket) репозитория, но сохранить их на production-сервере после выполнения команды git pull?

Решил уменьшить размер репозитория.
Заношу файл в .gitignore, затем делаю

```
git rm --cached --force <FILE_NAME> 
git commit -ma 'COMMIT_NAME'
git push
```

Захожу на production-сервер, делаю

```
git pull
```

и файлы удаляются там тоже.

Как этого избежать?

Comment: Из-за того, что вы в конкретном коммите удалите какой-либо файл, размер репозитория не уменьшится. Зачем вам на production сервере гит? Это безопасно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сохранить файлы вам придется на сервере переключиться на коммит где они есть, скопировать эти файлы в другую папаку, переключиться на коммит где их уже нет и скопировать обратно.

Но уменьшить размер репозитория это не поможет.

Единственный способ уменьшить размер - это отредактировать все коммиты в истории где эти файлы были, удалив их. После чего перетереть историю на сервере. Обновиться на всех локальных копиях. И выполнить git gc. Внимание! после работы gc вернуть уже невозможно!